# F.3 Operations, 9 lists 5 FE_ macros followed by 4 IEEE 754 rounding-direction attributes ending up with "respectively": mistake?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, rounding, standards, c17

N2479 C17..C2x working draft — February 5, 2020 ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E):
F.3 Operations, 9:

> The macros  (7.6) FE_DOWNWARD, FE_TONEAREST, FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO, FE_TOWARDZERO, and
> FE_UPWARD, which are  used in conjunction with the fegetround and fesetround functions
> and the FENV_ROUND  pragma,  represent the IEC 60559 rounding-direction  attributes  roundTowardNegative, roundTiesToEven, roundTowardZero, and roundTowardPositive, respectively. Support for the  roundTiesToAway attribute  for  binary floating-point  arithmetic,  and  hence for the FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO  macro, is optional.

Let's recap:

```
C                      IEEE 754              Comment     
FE_DOWNWARD            roundTowardNegative
FE_TONEAREST           roundTiesToEven
FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO   roundTiesToAway       roundTiesToAway is missing in the sentence #1
FE_TOWARDZERO          roundTowardZero
FE_UPWARD              roundTowardPositive
```

The issue: sentence #1 lists 5 `FE_` macros followed by 4 IEEE 754 rounding-direction attributes ending with "respectively".

Is a mistake / typo? Can someone who has the latest published version of the standard check it?

Comment: Hm, isn't this common English? Like in "The sky and grass are blue and green, respectively."

Comment: @thebusybee: Yeah, but one was left out, so it's like "The sky, grass and sun are blue and yellow, respectively."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects has a later draft, N2596, dated December 11, 2020.  It has the text corrected, with `roundTiesToAway` inserted where it belongs:

> The macros (7.6) FE_DOWNWARD , FE_TONEAREST , FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO , FE_TOWARDZERO , and
> FE_UPWARD , which are used in conjunction with the fegetroundand fesetroundfunctions and the
> FENV_ROUND pragma, represent the IEC 60559 rounding-direction attributes roundTowardNegative,
> roundTiesToEven, **roundTiesToAway**, roundTowardZero, and roundTowardPositive, respectively,
> for binary floating-point arithmetic. Support for the roundTiesToAway attribute for binary floating-
> point arithmetic, and hence for the FE_TONEARESTFROMZERO macro, is optional.

It seems clear that this was just an editing error.